# Batch File conditions

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am trying to create a batch file, where based on criteria, it will go to a section in the batch file. At the moment its only partially working. If I choose 'Y' for installing 'Holmes' , 'N' for 'ReportServer' and 'N' for 'Apache' then it will prompt me for "Enter SQLServerName". However if I choose 'N' for installing Holmes and 'Y' for installing 'ReportServer' then it should ask me the same question to "Enter SQLServername", but at the moment it goes to end. Anyone know what to do to get this working correctly?

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set SETTINGS_FILE=c:\temp\settings.txt

if "%InstallHolmes%"=="" (
    choice /C yn /N /M "Do you want to install Holmes?  : "
    if %ERRORLEVEL% ==1 (
       set InstallHolmes=Y
    ) else (
       set InstallHolmes=N
    )
    echo InstallHolmes=!InstallHolmes! >> %SETTINGS_FILE%
)

    if "%InstallReportServer%"=="" (
    choice /C yn /N /M "Do you want to install Report Server? : "
    if %ERRORLEVEL% ==1 (
        set InstallReportServer=Y
    ) else (
        set InstallReportServer=N)
    )
    echo InstallReportServer=!InstallReportServer! >> %SETTINGS_FILE%
)

if "%InstallApache%"=="" (
    choice /C yn /N /M "Do you want to install Apache? : "
    if %ERRORLEVEL% ==1 (
       set InstallApache=Y
     ) else (
       set InstallApache=N
    )
    echo InstallApache=!InstallApache! >> %SETTINGS_FILE%
)
set "TRUE="
if "%InstallHolmes%"=="Y" set TRUE=1
if "%InstallReportServer%"=="Y" set TRUE=1
if "%TRUE%" == "1" set InstallEitherAppOrReports=Y
if "%TRUE%" == "1" goto sqlinfo

set "TRUE="
if "%InstallHolmes%"=="N" set TRUE=2
if "%InstallReportServer%"=="N" set TRUE=2 
if "%TRUE%" == "2" goto end

:sqlinfo 

if "%SQLServer%"=="" (
    set /p SQLServer="Enter SQLServer name     : "
    echo SQLServer=!SQLServer!>> %SETTINGS_FILE%
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1st observation:

```
if "%InstallHolmes%"=="" (
    choice /C yn /N /M "Do you want to install Holmes?  : "
    if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 1 (
       set "InstallHolmes=Y"
    ) else (
       set "InstallHolmes=N"
    )
    rem `echo InstallHolmes` moved outside the `IF-block` to be always logged 
)
echo InstallHolmes=!InstallHolmes! >> %SETTINGS_FILE%
```

- `!ERRORLEVEL!` instead of `%ERRORLEVEL%` as the `ERRORLEVEL` variable is changed by preceding `choice` command *inside a code block in parentheses* and therefore `%ERRORLEVEL%` evaluates to it's value before opening parenthesis in parsing phase;
- `EQU` (numeric comparison) instead of `==` (string comparison);
- `echo InstallHolmes` moved (see comment in above code snippet);
- note quoting in `set "InstallHolmes=Y"` (always use `set "variable=value"` syntax pattern to avoid unwanted trailing characters, e.g. spaces). You could see the double quotes importance below in your code:
  there is  `set InstallReportServer=N)` with unwanted closing parenthesis and a trailing space somewhere in `set TRUE=2` (copy & paste the `if "%InstallReportServer%"=="N" set TRUE=2` line)...

2nd observation: next code snippet works like logical `OR`:

```
set "TRUE="
if "%InstallHolmes%"=="Y" set "TRUE=1"
if "%InstallReportServer%"=="Y" set "TRUE=1"
```

Hence, following `if "%TRUE%" == "1" goto sqlinfo` is valid in all `YY`, `YN`, `NY` case of `%InstallHolmes%%InstallReportServer%` and invalid only in the `NN` case.

Logical `AND` could be either

```
if "%InstallHolmes%%InstallReportServer%" == "YY" set "TRUE=1"
```

or

```
if "%InstallHolmes%"=="Y" if "%InstallReportServer%"=="Y" set "TRUE=1"
```

3rd observation: avoid unwanted performing a code which succeed a *conditional* `goto` as follows:

```
if "%TRUE%" == "2" goto end

echo script should not reach the :sqlinfo label line 
goto :somewhere
:sqlinfo
```